# I can't get my startup script running

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, gnome, suspend

I have been following the tutorial [How to run script on startup on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Server/Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop) to try to run something on startup:

I've done everything exactly how they ask, and the script still doesn't run. I put a sound in to make sure it wasn't just running when I couldn't see, and it will not run. I don't know what's going on. Here's the code of the service and the script it runs:

```
openup.sh
#!/bin/bash
play /home/synthetichuman/Downloads/br2rotr/2a1d14277eb3aacfcda04a0b57d78cc4.wav
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/1.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/2.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/3.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/4.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/5.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/6.jpg" & sleep 0.5
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/synthetichuman/Pictures/7.jpg" & sleep 0.5
```

```
openup.service
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/openup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Edit: Turns out, I've been going about it wrong. I figured it out, though.

Comment: I have no idea, but I have recently done the same thing following this post: https://www.howtogeek.com/687970/how-to-run-a-linux-program-at-startup-with-systemd/

Comment: It's unclear if you want this scrip[t to run before or after login. Use the full path to "play". Gnome-shell is not running when network.service completes, so all those background picture changes are wasted effort before login. Gnome shell does not start until after login.

Comment: I want the script to run after login. What should I specify for that?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you have solved the problem yourself. This may be helpful to others with the same problem.

Comment: You should answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I've been going about it wrong. In order to run a script when the Gnome shell boots up, use the command `gnome-session-properties` and add a .sh script to it.